Authentication failed while cloning GitHub repository despite correct credentials
am attempting to clone a GitHub repository using HTTPS with my correct GitHub username (hariprasath) and password, but I am consistently encountering an "Authentication failed" error:
git clone "https://github.com/hariprasath2003/sql.git"
Cloning into 'sql'...
Username for 'https://github.com': hariprasath
Password for 'https://hariprasath@github.com':
remote: Invalid username or password.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/hariprasath2003/sql.git/'
I have double-checked my credentials and they are accurate. What might be causing this issue, and how can I resolve it to successfully clone the repository? Should I consider using a personal access token (PAT) instead of password authentication, and if so, what steps are involved in using a PAT for cloning?

try SSH. PAT is for GitHub API, Git operations only supports HTTPS and SSH
